# Label Data for Classification in Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, matrix, char, cell-array

I have 2 sets of train data, `A` and `B` with different sizes,  which I want to use for training the classifier, and I have 2 labels in 2 *char* variables like,

```
L1 = 'label A';
L2 = 'label B';
```

How can I produce appropriate labels ?

I will use `cat(1,A,B);` to merge data first.

Depending on the `size(A,1)` and `size(B,1)`, It should be something like,

```
label = ['label A'
         'label A'
         'label A' 
         .
         .
         'label B'
         'label B'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the following:

```
na = size(A,1);
nb = size(B,1);
```

Here are a few ways to create the cell-array of labels:

1. repmat

   ```
   labels = [repmat({'label A'},na,1); repmat({'label B'},nb,1)];
   ```
2. cell-array filling

   ```
   labels = cell(na+nb,1);
   labels(1:na)     = {'label A'};
   labels(na+1:end) = {'label B'};
   ```
3. cell-array linear indexing

   ```
   labels = {'label A'; 'label B'};
   labels = labels([1*ones(na,1); 2*ones(nb,1)]);
   ```
4. cell-array linear indexing (another)

   ```
   idx = zeros(na+nb,1); idx(nb-1)=1; idx = cumsum(idx)+1;
   labels = {'label A'; 'label B'};
   labels = labels(idx);
   ```
5. num2str

   ```
   labels = cellstr(num2str((1:(na+nb) > na).' + 'A', 'label %c'));
   ```
6. strcat

   ```
   idx = [1*ones(na,1); 2*ones(nb,1)];
   labels = strcat({'label '}, char(idx+'A'-1));
   ```

... you get the idea :)

---

Note that it's always easy to convert between a cell-array of strings and a char-matrix:

```
% from cell-array of strings to a char matrix
clabels = char(labels);

% from a char matrix to a cell-array of strings
labels = cellstr(clabels);
```

Comment: lets see if others can think of more ways :)

Comment: A little crazy, but also possible is `labels = cell(na+nb,1);` `[labels{1:na}] = deal('label A');` and `[labels{na+1:end}] = deal('label B');`.

Comment: @JandeGier: not crazy at all, good way to show the `deal` function

Answer (score 1):

If the label names have the same length, you create an array like so:

```
L = [repmat(L1,size(A,1),1);repmat(L2,size(B,1),1)];
```

Otherwise, you need to use a cell array:

```
L = [repmat({L1},size(A,1),1);repmat({L2},size(B,1),1)];
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it wouldn't be so hard, I just couldn't find a way to replicate _char_, but as you said `repmat` is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
label = [repmat('label A',size(A,1),1); repmat('label B',size(B,1),1) ];
```

This will create the label matrix you are looking for. You need to use [repmat](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html). Repmat helps you to repeat a certain value many times